# Only sum up unique values in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |       A                B           
---|----------------------------------------- 
1  |    Total              1.600
---|-----------------------------------------
2  |    Product_A_x1         700        
3  |    Product_A_x5         700  
---|-----------------------------------------      
4  |    Product_B_x3         300        
---|-----------------------------------------
5  |    Product_C_x4         200      
6  |    Product_C_x8         200      
---|------------------------------------------
7  |    Product_D_x9         400         
8  |    Product_D_x11        400      
9  |    Prodcut_D_x8         400  
10 |
```

---

In Cell `B1` I want to **sum** the **unique values** from `Column B`.

```
B1 = 700 + 300 + 200 + 400
```

In case a value appears two times it should **only be included one time** in the `sum` function.

---

Is there somehting like a `SUMIF` formula for **unique values**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft365 you can use:
`=SUM(UNIQUE(B2:B9))`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have 365, you can use the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B2:B9,B2:B9&""),B2:B9)
```

further explained on [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1705-excel-sum-average-unique-values.html).