# Sum up unique values in column per criteria in other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |       A                 B           
---|----------------------------------------- 
1  |    Total              1.900
---|-----------------------------------------
2  |    Product_A           700        
3  |    Product_A           700  
---|-----------------------------------------      
4  |    Product_B           300        
---|-----------------------------------------
5  |    Product_C           200      
6  |    Product_C           200      
---|------------------------------------------
7  |    Product_D           700         
8  |    Product_D           700      
9  |    Prodcut_D           700  
10 |
```

---

In Cell `B1` I want to sum the **unique values** in `Column B` **per product** in `Column A`.

```
B1 = 700 + 300 + 200 + 700
```

Currently, in Cell `B1` I use the formular from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347608/only-sum-up-unique-values-in-column) which is `=SUM(UNIQUE(B2:B9))`. 
However, with this formula I get `1.200` as result because it does not include the `700` from `Product_D`.

---

How do I have to modify the formula so it `sums up` the **values unique per product**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have `UNIQUE()` function then you can use it with index and sum like-

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:B9),,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try `SUMPRODUCT` instead.

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B9/COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9))`

It will get you the sum of values in B for unique values in A.

Note: this is assuming,the values in `B2:B9` are all numeric. If not you will get a #VALUE error