# Sum up unique values in column per criteria in other column (if columns are filtered)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

With reference to [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348101/sum-up-unique-values-in-column-per-criteria-in-other-column) in `Cell B1` I use the formula `=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:B9),,2))` in order to only `sumup` the **unique values per product**.

All this works perfectly.

---

Now, I set a `filter` in `Column A` and exclude for example `Product_A` and `Product_C` from the list:

[image]

As you can see the `1.900` in `Cell B1` remains. However, I only want to apply the formula in `Cell B1` to the filtered data which means that - in this case - the value in `Cell B1` should be `1.000`.

---

Normally, I could achieve this with a `SUBTOTAL` formula but I do not have any clue how I can combine the `UNIQUE` and `INDEX` function with the `SUBTOTAL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a stretch to be honest:

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A2:A9,ROW(A2:A9)-ROW(A2),1,1)),A2:B9)),,2))
```

You could always just avoid the volatile function and use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:B9,(A2:A9<>"Product_A")*(A2:A9<>"Product_C"))),0,2))
```

Comment: The second formula does not work on my side. I get 1.900. The first one gives back the expected 1.000

Comment: I tried but it sitll does not work. Ist he UNIEK a typo?

Comment: @Michi, Dang, yes that was the Dutch equivalent to `UNIQUE()`

Comment: mmh, on my side it sitll returns the 1.900.

Comment: I also changed everything in column A from Product_A, Product_B, ... to just A,B,C,D. The first formula works without any issue. The second one does not change on any filter I set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226557/discussion-between-jvdv-and-michi).

Comment: As figured out in the chat the second formula basically includes the filter into the formula so it can be used in case someone does not want to apply the "normal" Excel filters.