# Sum up unique values in column per criteria in other column (if values are on the left side of the criteria column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |       A                 B           
---|----------------------------------------- 
1  |     1.900            
---|-----------------------------------------
2  |       700           Product_A  
3  |       700           Product_A
---|-----------------------------------------      
4  |       300           Product_B     
---|-----------------------------------------
5  |       200           Product_C  
6  |       200           Product_C
---|------------------------------------------
7  |       700           Product_D     
8  |       700           Product_D 
9  |       700           Prodcut_D
10 |
```

With reference to the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490849/sum-up-unique-values-in-column-per-criteria-in-other-column-if-columns-are-filt/65491285#65491285) I wanted to `sum up` the **unique values per product** in `Cell A1`. 
Therefore, I tried to go with this formula:

```
A1 =SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(IF(SUBTOTAL(2;OFFSET(B2:B9;ROW(B2:B9)-ROW(B2);1;1));A2:B9));;1))
```

However, as a result now I get `0` instead of `1.900`. 
I assume the issue results because I have the values on the **left side** of the **criteria column**. 
Do you have any idea how I need to modify the formula to also make it work in the displayed column order?

Comment: It looks as though the original question was about unique sum with filtering and that's where the subtotal came from - are you still filtering in this question?

Comment: Yeah, the filter option should still be possible.

Comment: Why not sumifs()?

Comment: Of course 3rd time lucky... ie post again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed to do was to change the `1` into `-1` on the `OFFSET()`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(B2:B9,ROW(B2:B9)-ROW(B2),-1,1)),A2:B9)),,1))
```